# After WAMP update & migrate, mysql tables have no structure / primary keys

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, wamp

We've moved WAMP to another drive on our server - the old version was WAMP 2.4, and the new one is WAMP 2.5. We installed 2.5 fresh on the new drive, and copied the www and mysql data folders from the old install.

It's 'working' - sites appear to run fine - but I've discovered that the database structure appears to be gone. All database tables have no primary keys, and no visible structure in phpMyAdmin.

This is the case for databases brought into the new WAMP install in the mysql data folder as well as new databases: I can export a database with structure from a remote server, but after importing to the local WAMP server the structure is stripped.

Two questions:

(How) can the database structure be restored?

How can I create or import new databases with structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curiously this sorted itself out after attempting to troubleshoot the issue then undoing changes. What we tried:

- Restarted all WAMP services, exited and reopened WAMP - unsuccessful.
- Copied entire old mysql folder to new WAMP install, attempted to run mysql service with old mysql version - unsuccessful.
- Reverted to newer version of mysql that came with WAMP 2.5 (back to initial state before troubleshooting), restarted services - unsuccessful.
- Waited 10 minutes - table structure returned, working correctly.

This leads me to believe there was an interaction with another process or condition on the server, rather than a misconfiguration of WAMP.